# In an ansi style keyboard, what is the vk code for the backslash above enter

Tags: virtual-keyboard

i can't for the love of me find the vk code for this, i want to make a program which detects if it's been pressed and uses send input to input a < instead of ç

I'm not using autohotkey because it would be half as fun as coding it myself and like using a chainsaw to cut a piece of steak

Comment: Did you mean a \ and not a <?

Comment: @KenWhite It could also be `VK_OEM_5`: "*For the US standard keyboard, the '\|' key*", which is the key directly above `Enter` on my keyboard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Good catch. I missed that one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: A quick test app says it's yours, not mine. I've removed my comment. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the vk code for the backslash above enter

It really depends on your keyboard.

Per the [Virtual Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) documentation, it is likely `VK_OEM_5`:

> VK_OEM_5
> 0xDC
>
> Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
> **For the US standard keyboard, the '\|' key**

Which is indeed the <kbd>\</kbd> key above the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on *my* keyboard.

But, if you don't have a US keyboard, then it *may* be `VK_OEM_102` instead:

> VK_OEM_102
> 0xE2
>
> Either the angle bracket key **or the backslash key** on the RT 102-key keyboard

So, you will just have to write some code to test which key code is actually reported when pressing the <kbd>\</kbd> key on *your* keyboard.